I deleted Python 3.12 in my Ubuntu 24.04 , now have problems with system. How can I fix it?
I manually sudo rm -rf-ed some python3.12 packages in /usr/bin/, after installing 3.13 thinking that it will be okay but my system went out and I cant even start terminal, I need to write on vscodes terminal and all attempts to install something will show dpkg errors
deleted all dirs containing .12 so my /usr/bin/ looks like that
/usr/bin/py
py3clean           py3versions        pybabel-python3    pydoc3.13          pygettext3.13      pyserial-miniterm  python3.10
py3compile         pybabel            pydoc3.10          pygettext3.10      pygmentize         pyserial-ports     python3.13

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-sss package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cloud-init_24.4-0ubuntu1~24.04.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-sss_2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

or
bekarys@bekarys-hp:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cloud-init python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-sss
Suggested packages:
  openssh-server ssh-import-id python3-zstandard
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cloud-init python3-apport python3-problem-report python3-sss
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/766 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 257523 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cloud-init_24.4-0ubuntu1~24.04.2_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cloud-init.prerm: 21: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old cloud-init package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 21: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cloud-init_24.4-0ubuntu1~24.04.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 new cloud-init package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cloud-init.postinst: 410: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed cloud-init package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-problem-report package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-problem-report package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-sss_2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-sss.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3-sss package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-sss_2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-sss package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-sss.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-sss package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cloud-init_24.4-0ubuntu1~24.04.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.28.1-0ubuntu3.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-sss_2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


This answer should be helpful. Just change 3.10 to 3.12
